# How  to check if html element has some html tag by jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

The case : should select object

example:

```
function getDomPart(text,htmlTag){
    return $(text).closest(htmlTag).get(0);
}

var text1='<object>some text + html elements  </object>';
var text2='<div><object>some text + html elements  </object></div>';
alert(getDomPart(text1,'object'));
alert(getDomPart(text2,'object'));
```

the result should be: some text + html elements  
but its not.

please tell me what should be fixed.

Edit:
please see my answer with short solution.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. it's DOMelement and undifined. see my answer.

Comment: @gdoron: No, I am trying to train the OP to ask better questions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit. **=)** sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that i get idea about : add wrapper element then can be used only find :

```
function search(text,htmlTag){
    return  $('<div>'+text+'</div>').find(htmlTag).html();
}


var text1='<object>some text + html elements  </object>';
var text2='<div><object>some text + html elements  </object></div>';
alert(search(text1,'object'));
alert(search(text2,'object'));
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/EaZrs/5/

Answer (score 2):

closest is searching the DOM up, not down like `find`.

[closest docs:](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> Description: Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.

[`find docs:`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

so for text1 it should be `closest` and for text2 it should be `find` :

```
function getDomPartUp(text,htmlTag){
    return $(text).closest(htmlTag).html();
}

function getDomPartDown(text,htmlTag){
    return $(text).find(htmlTag).html();
}

var text1='<object>some text + html elements  </object>';
var text2='<div><object>some text + html elements  </object></div>';
alert(getDomPartUp(text1,'object'));
alert(getDomPartDown(text2,'object'));​
```

Use `.html` to get the text you wanted.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EaZrs/)**

---

**Update:**

To do it in one method:

```
function search(text,htmlTag){
    var $up = $(text).closest(htmlTag);

    if ($up.length > 0)
        return $up.html();

    var $down = $(text).find(htmlTag);

    return $down.length > 0 ? $down.html() :"";
}    

var text1='<object>some text + html elements  </object>';
var text2='<div><object>some text + html elements  </object></div>';
alert(search(text1,'object'));
alert(search(text2,'object'));​
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EaZrs/2/)

Comment: 1. $(text) should convert to dom? 2.what is your code instead my?3. find also not works for text1

Comment: @Yosef. No that `<object> ... </object>` should be in the page-DOM not just a string.

Comment: can you please give reference for that??or write solution that will work?

Comment: ok, thanks for the code. the problem that i cant know what should be the value of text var -  i bring examples of 2 possible cases of text var. according that how will you change the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `find()` for the element's children and `andSelf()` to get the element itself.